# CSS transition time not applied on transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a div that should slide to the left smoothly over .5s. Right now it's instantly popping to its new position, not sliding.

I'm using jQuery to apply a tranlsateX to the div after a button is pushed. It triggers some ajax which adds a transform to the div's css (at bottom):

```
 $.ajax({
         method: 'POST',
         url: '/cities/popup',
         data: { latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude },
         dataType: 'html',
         success: function(data){
          $(".popup").css("display", "block");
          $(".popup").empty();
          $(".popup").append(data);
          $(".popup").css("transform", "translateX(-100%)");
 });
```

Here's all of the styling on the popup class, notice that I'm defining transform time should be 3s at the end of the code block.

```
.popup{
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: scroll;
  z-index: 5;
  right: -40%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -6px 5px 35px 0px rgba(133,133,133,0.53);
  -moz-box-shadow: -6px 5px 35px 0px rgba(133,133,133,0.53);
  box-shadow: -6px 5px 35px 0px rgba(133,133,133,0.53);
  transition: transform 3s;
}
```

The transform is working, the div moves, but it's not an animated movement over .5s, simply appears in the new spot instantly. I'm really not sure how to begin troubleshooting this.

Comment: Not sure what browser you are using but you may want to make sure you cover all options -webkit-, -moz-, -ms-, -o- (last two if applicable).

Comment: @Gacci - Note that [the only prefix that would even need to be considered would be `-webkit-`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions), the native property is almost universally supported.

Comment: That's why I added "if applicable"

Answer (score 2):

### The cause

The transition doesn't work because of `display: none`. `display: none` to `display: block` can't be animated, so it breaks the transition.

### Solution

One solution is to hide the element without using `display: none`. The following example works when the div is hidden with `opacity: 0` and shown with `opacity: 1`.

> **Note**: where `display: none` removes the element completely, `opacity: 0` simply hides it and it can still be interacted with. For
>   example, if it is positioned over a link you will not be able to click
>   the link because of the invisible div.
>
> To overcome this, you could consider [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) (see
>   [browser compatiblity](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)) so that click events pass beneath it. You
>   would then change it back to `pointer-events: auto` when shown, so it
>   can be clicked.

#### Basic example

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #F00;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
body:hover div {
  transform: translateX(100px);
}
/*Will work*/

.willTransition {
  opacity: 0;
}
body:hover .willTransition {
  opacity: 1;
}
/*Doesn't work*/

.wontTransition {
  display: none;
}
body:hover .wontTransition {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1> Hover anywhere here to show!</h1>

<h2>Will transition with opacity</h2>
<div class="willTransition"></div>
<h2>Wont transition with display none to block</h2>
<div class="wontTransition"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
transition: all 3s ease;
```

Probably its not taking the transform property in particular.

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately no difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
transition: all 3s ease 0s;
```

Solved!

Comment: Tried this, no difference :(.

Comment: maybe you can start working with jquery animate. You can check the docu here [http://api.jquery.com/animate/](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score -1):

I think the better idea is add class on popup. It's easiest way